# Ejercicio en PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Codifica un procedimiento que reciba como parámetros un número de departamento, un importe y un porcentaje y que suba el salario a todos los empleados del departamento indicado en la llamada. La subida será el porcentaje o el importe que se indica en la llamada (el que sea más beneficioso para el empleado en cada caso). Indicar al finalizar el número de filas actualizadas.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE actualizacion (numeroDepartamento NUMBER, importe NUMBER, porcentaje NUMBER)
AS
CURSOR c_empleados IS
SELECT salario FROM emple WHERE dept_no=numeroDepartamento FOR UPDATE;
v_regEmpleados c_empleados%ROWTYPE;
v_importe NUMBER(3);
v_porcentaje NUMBER(4,1);
BEGIN
OPEN c_empleados;
    FETCH c_empleados INTO v_regEmpleados;
    WHILE c_empleados %FOUND LOOP
    v_porcentaje:=(v_regEmpleados.salario/100)*porcentaje;
    v_importe:=v_regEmpleados.salario+importe;
        IF (v_importe > v_porcentaje) THEN
          UPDATE emple SET salario=salario+v_importe
            WHERE CURRENT OF c_empleados;
        ELSE
            UPDATE emple SET salario=salario+v_porcentaje
                WHERE CURRENT OF c_empleados;
          END IF;      
    FETCH c_empleados INTO v_regEmpleados;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_empleados;
END;
```

No encuentro el error, y no se donde tendría que poner %rowcount para que me contara las filas actualizadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para estos casos, indicar el mensaje de error nos facilitaría mas decirte que puede fallar. Aún asi, veo un error en la forma en la que recibes los parámetros, te falta indicar si se trata de entrada, salida o entrada/salida. Sería algo así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE actualizacion (numeroDepartamento IN NUMBER, importe IN NUMBER, porcentaje IN NUMBER)
```

Por otro lado, yo no usaría el rowcount. Añadiría una variable contadora que se incremente en cada iteración del bucle. Finalmente, añadiendo las recomendaciones de B. Pato, el procedimiento sería algo como esto (puede que haya algún error, no tengo Oracle instalado en esta máquina y me es imposible probar):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE actualizacion (numeroDepartamento IN NUMBER, importe IN NUMBER, porcentaje IN NUMBER)
IS
    CURSOR c_empleados IS
        SELECT salario FROM emple WHERE dept_no=numeroDepartamento FOR UPDATE;
    v_regEmpleados c_empleados%ROWTYPE;
    v_importe NUMBER(3);
    v_porcentaje NUMBER(4,1);
    v_affectedRow NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_empleados;
    FETCH c_empleados INTO v_regEmpleados;
    WHILE c_empleados%FOUND LOOP
        v_porcentaje:=(v_regEmpleados.salario/100)*porcentaje;
        v_importe:=v_regEmpleados.salario+importe;

        IF (v_importe > v_porcentaje) THEN
            UPDATE emple SET salario=salario+v_importe
            WHERE CURRENT OF c_empleados;
        ELSE
            UPDATE emple SET salario=salario+v_porcentaje
            WHERE CURRENT OF c_empleados;
        END IF;    

        v_affectedRow := v_affectedRow + 1;

        FETCH c_empleados INTO v_regEmpleados;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c_empleados;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Los procedimientos creo que se estructuraban con IS no AS:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE...
IS
BEGIN
END;
```

Luego en el bucle para recorrer el cursor creo que deberían ir juntos c_empleados%FOUND

Añadir que para recorrer cursores yo usaba más:

```
LOOP
   FETCH [cursor] INTO [variable];
   EXIT WHEN [cursor]%NOTFOUND;
   ...
END LOOP;
```

Hace tiempo que no lo toco desde el curso, espero haberte dado algo de luz