# ¿ Cómo creo un cursor para esta consulta?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

recientemente he hecho este código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ex1 (codigo constituent.cod_constituent%TYPE)
IS
  nif empresaproductora.nif_empresa%type;
  nom empresaproductora.nom_empresa%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT nif_empresa, nom_empresa
  INTO nif,nom
  FROM empresaproductora 
  WHERE nif_empresa IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT nif_empresa 
       FROM residu_constituent
       WHERE cod_constituent = codigo);
END ex1;
```

El programa no funciona por qué da mas de una fila, para ello necesito crear un cursor, es ahí cuando me pierdo, ¿ alguien sabe como puedo crear un cursor que me recorra la consulta ?

Comment: Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153870/ejercicio-en-pl-sql/153984#153984

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ex1 (codigo constituent.cod_constituent%TYPE)
IS
  CURSOR c1 IS
  SELECT nif_empresa, nom_empresa
  FROM empresaproductora 
  WHERE nif_empresa IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT nif_empresa 
       FROM residu_constituent
       WHERE cod_constituent = codigo);
  nif empresaproductora%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR nif IN c1
  LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (nif.nif_empresa || '' ||nif.nom_empresa);
  END LOOP;
END ex1;
```